# How does a Thread notify the main thread, while the main thread is still running

Tags: java, multithreading

I am a beginner for Java. I want to implement a Timer by spawning a Thread. The way I want to run is that the main thread should continue working even after spawning the thread. However once the thread completes the Task, it should notify the main thread that the task is done.I looked at Thread.join() and Thread.sleep(). For both these methods, the main thread waits for the thread to complete the task. However I want the main thread to keep on running.

I have written a code below, where the main thread calls a thread, and the thread executes the task for 10 s. However I am not able to notify the main thread about the task completion. 
Kindly help me out.

```
public class MainThreadtest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      dispthread2 dt2 = new dispthread2();
      dt2.start();
      System.out.println("Thread dt2 has started");
   }
}
```

second class

```
public class dispthread2 extends Thread {
   public void run() {
      long endTimemillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;
      while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTimemillis) {
      }
      System.out.println("The task is done");
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use thread.join() to wait for a thread to complete running, before continuing execution.

Comment: Your wish is wrong: what you want would have to amount to an "I/O interrupt" where a thread is interrupted in the midst of whatever it is doing, and goes on to handle the event.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this that does not require use of Thread#join and thus allows the two threads to run independently:

1. Use an Observer Pattern listener interface, such as which can be obtained via Java Beans PropertyChangeSupport and a PropertyChangeListener.
2. Don't extend Thread but instead implement Runnable.

---

For example:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

import javax.swing.event.SwingPropertyChangeSupport;

public class MainThreadTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      DispThread2 dt2 = new DispThread2();
      dt2.addPropertyChangeListener(DispThread2.STATE, new PropertyChangeListener() {

         @Override
         public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("DT2 Thread state (from Main Thread): " + evt.getNewValue());
            if (evt.getNewValue() == DispThreadState.DONE) {
               System.out.println("Thread dt2 is now done (from Main Thread)");
            }
         }
      });
      new Thread(dt2, "DT2").start();
      System.out.println("Thread dt2 has started");
   }
}

class DispThread2 implements Runnable {
   public static final String STATE = "state";
   private volatile DispThreadState state = DispThreadState.PENDING;
   private PropertyChangeSupport support = new SwingPropertyChangeSupport(this);

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      support.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void addPropertyChangeListener(String propertyName, PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      support.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyName, listener);
   }

   public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
      support.removePropertyChangeListener(listener);
   }

   public void run() {
      setState(DispThreadState.RUNNING);
      long endTimemillis = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;
      while (System.currentTimeMillis() < endTimemillis) {
      }
      System.out.println("The task is done");
      setState(DispThreadState.DONE);
   }

   public DispThreadState getState() {
      return state;
   }

   public void setState(DispThreadState state) {
      DispThreadState oldValue = this.state;
      DispThreadState newValue = state;
      this.state = state;
      support.firePropertyChange(STATE, oldValue, newValue);
   }
}

enum DispThreadState {
   PENDING, RUNNING, DONE
}
```